# MS Access 2016 Query Range vs Average per Day

Tags: sql, ms-access, range, average

I wanted to do up a query in Microsoft Access 2016 that shows the Range (maximum - minimum) vs Average per day.

I have done up a query that shows the results of all records between "16-Jun-16" and "17-Jun-16":

```
SELECT [Date Time], [Operation Grade-Load], [MFR g/10min]
FROM [In process analysis result]
WHERE ([Date Time] Between Date()-360 And Date()-358)
AND ([Operation Grade-Load] Like "MH*");
```

However, I am clueless on how I can proceed to modify my query to show the "Range" and "Average" of each day. I guess I should make use of Avg(), Max()-Min() functions. Can anyone guide me on this?

Edit:
Per day is calculated based between [Previous Day 02:00:00] and [Today 02:00:00].
Example:

- 16-Jun-16 = row records between "16-Jun-16 02:00:00" and "17-Jun-16
  02:00:00"
- 17-Jun-16 = row records between "17-Jun-16 02:00:00" and
  "18-Jun-16 02:00:00"
- ...

Is it even possible to calculate dates based on this logic?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

[image]

Edit 1:
I updated my SQL query:

```
SELECT [Date Time], [Range], [Average]
FROM [In process analysis result], (SELECT Max([MFR g/10min])-Min([MFR g/10min]) AS [Range], Avg([MFR g/10min]) AS Average
FROM [In process analysis result]
WHERE ((([In process analysis result].[Date Time]) Between Date()-360 And Date()-358) AND (([In process analysis result].[Operation Grade-Load]) Like "MH*"))
)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
WHERE ((([In process analysis result].[Date Time]) Between Date()-360 And Date()-358) AND (([In process analysis result].[Operation Grade-Load]) Like "MH*"))
ORDER BY [In process analysis result].[Date Time];
```

And it turned out to be close enough to what I wanted... but not yet, as it's not calculated based on per day.

[image]

Edit 2:
Here is the expected outcome:

[image]

Edit 3:
Following @USeptim, this is the result of the query that was created. However, it creates another two columns with [Range] and [PromedioDeMFR g/10min].

[image]

Comment: show us an example of your expected outcome

Comment: @dbajtr Please see Edit 2 in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT [In process analysis result].[Date Time], [In process analysis 
result].[MFR g/10min], QueryAux.Range, QueryAux.[PromedioDeMFR g/10min]
FROM [In process analysis result] INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Max([MFR g/10min])-Min([MFR g/10min]) AS Range, Avg([In process 
analysis result].[MFR g/10min]) AS [PromedioDeMFR g/10min], [In process 
analysis result].[Date Time], [In process analysis result].[Operation Grade-
Load]
FROM [In process analysis result]
GROUP BY [In process analysis result].[Date Time], [In process analysis 
result].[Operation Grade-Load]) QueryAux 
ON ([In process analysis result].[Operation Grade-Load] = QueryAux.
[Operation Grade-Load]) AND ([In process analysis result].[Date Time] = 
QueryAux.[Date Time])
WHERE ((([In process analysis result].[Date Time]) Between Date()-360 And 
Date()-358) AND (([In process analysis result].[Operation Grade-Load]) Like 
"MH*"))
ORDER BY [In process analysis result].[Date Time];
```

You can create a a query with the subquery that I have called "query aux" and reference it directly.

Comment: Thanks sir. I ran the query and it showed me what I posted in Edit 3 of my original post. It created two additional columns, [Range] and [PromedioDeMFR g/10min]. What should I do with these two columns?

Comment: [PromedioDeMFR g/10min] should be called [Average], on the other hand,
 [Range] is a column shown in your query:                                      
SELECT Max([MFR g/10min])-Min([MFR g/10min]) AS [Range], Avg([MFR g/10min]) AS Average